# How can I make PyInstaller's .spec files actually portable? (woes absolute path for 'pathex' parameter)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

The PyInstaller `.spec` file is mean to be portable across the three platforms that it supports: Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

I find it much easier to generate the `.spec` file once and modify it at will before building an executable from it.

In every example on the Internet (e.g. [this one](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/10/a-pyinstaller-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/)), the `.spec` file would always define an absolute path in for the `pathex` parameter in the ANALYSIS section. This makes the build non-portable, because the absolute path is not only specific to the machine the build runs on, but also the platform.

Does this always have to be an absolute path or is there a way to make it completely portable?

Answer (score 20):

If you place the `.spec` file in its default location you can simply remove `pathex` from the spec because `'current directory'` and `'your-configured-pathex-here'` are identical.

**Explanation**

> `pathex` is an optional list of paths to be searched before `sys.path`

Source: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py#L123

> The spec file is actually executable Python code. PyInstaller builds the app by executing the contents of the spec file.

Source: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/doc/spec-files.rst#using-spec-files

This leads to the conclusion that you should be able either hardcode each path for the three environments like so

```
pathex=["/Users/fatuhoku/Python/myapp", "C:\\Python\\myapp", "/home/fatuhoku/Python/myapp"],
```

or call a handwoven Python function that just returns a list with a single element that is the current working directory.

If you run PyInstaller it tells you something like this:

```
46 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['current directory', 'your-configured-pathex-here']
```

Comment: you should put the last sentence at the beginning of your answer, or at least highligt it. Once I read that, I didn't need anything else.

Answer (score 9):

As others have pointed out, the `.spec` file is Python code. What you want is for `pathex` to be an absolute path on the machine currently executing the code. You can do this with the help of the `SPECPATH` global variable that is defined within the `.spec` file. (See all available globals listed in the PyInstaller docs [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#globals-available-to-the-spec-file).)

In our case, I used:

```
import os

spec_root = os.path.abspath(SPECPATH)

...

pathex=[spec_root]
```

If your `.spec` is not in the same directory as your package/script, you can use `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SPECPATH, '..'))` or something similar to find your pathex from your spec file.

Answer (score 2):

pathex now appears to be converted into a list of absolute paths if it isn't one already.

See [PyInstaller build.py line #426](http://www.pyinstaller.org/browser/project/PyInstaller/build.py)

The .spec file is certainly portable in that it's literally Python source code. :)
So you can write whatever logic you need inside your .spec file.

For example, my spec files call helper routines that exclude most of the encoding.* data that I don't care about, _ssl, etc...

Comment: Code currently at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py#L168?